# Joining SQL Temporal tables as-of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, temporal-tables

I'm attempting to do the following:

```
SELECT report.*,
doc.*
FROM report
FOR system_time ALL report
JOIN Document
FOR system_time as of <<report.BeginDate>> doc ON report.DocumentId = doc.DocumentId
```

Basically I'd like to get all the history of the parent table, and it's associated childrens table  as of the correct time according to the parents row. Is this possible?

Comment: What is "the correct time", the starting time or the end time for the parent row? Or do you all child rows that were active at any point between those times? I think you are going to need a manual date comparison, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166973/join-for-system-time-with-column-as-the-effective-system-time

Comment: The correct time of the child table is when it was within the start/end date of the parent table.

Comment: So why does your current query say `FOR system_time as of <<report.BeginDate>>`

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, `FOR SYSTEM_TIME` only allows a literal or a variable/parameter. It cannot be a column from the query. But you can put this into a inline Table Valued Function and then `APPLY` the function:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.DocumentAsOfDate (@documentId int, @asOfDate datetime(7))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
SELECT d.*
FROM dbo.Document FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF @asOfDate AS d
WHERE d.DocumentId = @documentId;

GO
```

```
SELECT
  report.*,
  doc.*
FROM report FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL report
CROSS APPLY dbo.DocumentAsOfDate (report.DocumentId, report.BeginDate) doc;
```

You may want to consider which date to use (start or end), and whether to use `FOR SYSTEM_TIME BETWEEN...` or other filter.

Comment: How could you adjust the TVF if you wanted the child table (I believe it is titled "Document" here) to be an input as well?

Comment: I think I've show that: a filter on `@documentId`

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your answer, but what I'm hoping to do is create one Table Valued Function that will work regardless of the child table, as I have many parent-child tables that will require this functionality. It seems that the child table in your TVF is static, i.e., you'd have to create a TVF for each child table that you want to join with the parent table. Is this correct? If yes, is there a way to change the TVF to be versatile enough to accept the child table as a parameter as well?

Comment: Correct, you need a TVF for every table. You cannot do it dynamically as TVFs cannot do dynamic SQL, and in any case it would be really messy. But you can use dynamic SQL to generate these functions, eg see https://dbfiddle.uk/F2huQnJs

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will probably go the TVF route, I'm just brainstorming if it's possible to create a single solution that could be re-used for any child table. Since stored procedures can use dynamic SQL, could you use a SP instead of a TVF to do this and select the result of the stored procedure and insert those results into a temp table? Maybe even if this is possible, as you alluded to, it would be so messy it wouldn't be worth it?

Comment: Well yeah, but it's really messy to do so (and not sure why you need a temp table, you can just `SELECT` the data straight out of dynamic SQL). I would recommend you instead just use functions as I said. It's reeally not a big deal, they're no worse than views. You would just need to specify up-front which function you want. Doing dynamic SQL is a usually a mistake: don't try to make a dynamic all-in-one solution, SQL really isn't good for that sort of thing.